# Cannot insert a new Calendar because of IllegalArgumentException in content values

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I want to insert a local calendar in `CalendarProvider`. Here is what I do:

```
Uri uri = asSyncAdapter(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, "Test", CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, "Test");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "Test Calendar (Added Programmatically)");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0x00FF00);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, "Test");

Uri insertUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

This method is copied from developer:

```
static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
    return uri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
}
```

However I have put value for name column, I get a similar exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: why down vote? without leaving comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I must explicitly put value for account name and account type:

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "Test");
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
```